# Wordpress Woocommerce product shortcodes

Tags: php, woocommerce, shortcode

[image]I am just checking in to see if anyone knows a way of just showing a products description via  short code or any other method without the image and description etc.

I have numerous articles regarding woo-commerce short code but nothing this specific. I am using this as part of a slider which I do not want the image of the product to show in there so just the product name and description and maybe price?

so I am editing archive-product.php

I have a slider within this page which I want to show a 'featured item' but with no image just the description:

```
  <?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>








<!-- Featured product title and desciption -->

<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //I saw maximum execution time error on your image - this is for that
$args = array(
   'post_status'    => 'publish',
   'post_type'      => 'product',
   'meta_value'     => 'yes',
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'product_cat'    => 'grammar'
);

$product_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<div class="shopBanner">
    <div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item" id="id1">

                <div class="section group">
                   <?php  if ($product_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                      <?php while ($product_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                          <div class="col span_2_of_3">
                          <h1><?php echo $product_query->post->post_title; ?></h1>
                          <h2 style="margin-top:-20px;">
                              <?php echo $product_query->post->post_excerpt; ?>
                          </h2>
                          </div>
                       <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <span class="icon lush-comments" id="heroIcon"></span>
                    </div>

                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>             
</div>  






    <!-- Link button to featured product -->

           <div class="section1" id="section1">
            <div class="container">
            <button class="mainbtn" style="float: left; margin-top: -82px;">View product</button>
                <div class="section group">
        <div class="col span_2_of_3">
              Take a look of our range of publications. Selected publications can be purchased via a download also.


        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
        <div style="float:right;">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><button class="social" style="background-image:url(img/twitterIcon.png);"></button></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><button class="social" style="background-image:url(img/facebookIcon.png);"></button></a>
        </div>
        </div>



            </div>
        </div>
        </div>




    <div class="section1"  style="padding: 0px 0 50px 0;">   
        <div class="container">
            <div style="background-color: #fff; width:100%; color: #777777;">
                <div style="padding: 20px; margin-bottom:-15px;">      



        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
             * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
        ?>





            <!--<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

                        <h3 style="color: #1dae5e; text-shadow:none; font-weight:600; font-size: 1.3em; margin-bottom:20px;"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h3>

            <?php endif; ?>-->



            <span style="float: right; margin-top:-40px;">

            <a class="shopNav" href="?post_type=product">Back to Shop</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a class="shopNav" href="?page_id=13">My Account</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a class="shopNav" href="?page_id=11">Basket</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a class="shopNav" href="?page_id=12">Checkout</a>

            </span>




      </div></div></div></div>  













    <div class="section1" style="padding: 40px 0 50px 0;">   
        <div class="container">
            <div style="background-color: #fff; width:100%; color: #777777;">
                <div style="padding: 20px;">           





            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
                ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

                <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
                ?>

            <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

                <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
        ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_sidebar hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
        ?>


            </div>
        </div>    
     </div>   
       </div> 



    <?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

Comment: You *might* be able to use a shortcode that display the *Content* (which is what a WooCommerce product description is). Have you tried a plugin like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-content-shortcodes/) with the Product ID? Would be more complex with Variable Products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will get the 10 products which are in **grammer** category and **status** is published. May be this will help.

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<!-- Featured product title and desciption -->

    <?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //I saw maximum execution time error on your image - this is for that
    $args = array(
       'post_status'    => 'publish',
       'post_type'      => 'product',
       'meta_value'     => 'yes',
       'posts_per_page' => 10,
       'product_cat'    => 'grammar'
    );
    $product_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
    <div class="shopBanner">
        <div class="container">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item" id="id1">
                    <div class="section group">
                        <?php while ( $product_query->have_posts() ) : $product_query->the_post(); global $product; ?>
                              <div class="col span_2_of_3">
                              <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                              <h2 style="margin-top:-20px;">
                                  <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post->post_excerpt ); ?>
                              </h2>
                              </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                            <span class="icon lush-comments" id="heroIcon"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Link button to featured product -->

    <div class="section1" id="section1">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="mainbtn" style="float: left; margin-top: -82px;">View product</button>
                <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_2_of_3">
              Take a look of our range of publications. Selected publications can be purchased via a download also.
            </div>
            <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                <div style="float:right;">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><button class="social" style="background-image:url(img/twitterIcon.png);"></button></a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><button class="social" style="background-image:url(img/facebookIcon.png);"></button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section1"  style="padding: 0px 0 50px 0;">
        <div class="container">
            <div style="background-color: #fff; width:100%; color: #777777;">
                <div style="padding: 20px; margin-bottom:-15px;">
                    <?php
                        /**
                         * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
                         *
                         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
                         * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
                         */
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
                    ?>

                    <?php //if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <!--                        <h3 style="color: #1dae5e; text-shadow:none; font-weight:600; font-size: 1.3em; margin-bottom:20px;"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h3>-->
                    <?php //endif; ?>

                    <span style="float: right; margin-top:-40px;">
                        <a class="shopNav" href="?post_type=product">Back to Shop</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a class="shopNav" href="?page_id=13">My Account</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a class="shopNav" href="?page_id=11">Basket</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a class="shopNav" href="?page_id=12">Checkout</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section1" style="padding: 40px 0 50px 0;">
        <div class="container">
            <div style="background-color: #fff; width:100%; color: #777777;">
                <div style="padding: 20px;">

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
                ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

                <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
                ?>

            <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

                <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
        ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_sidebar hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
        ?>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
       </div>

    <?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58428/discussion-between-stack-and-spiky-chathu).

Comment: Iv added an image to my question to show the result.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Also I saw there are no product description for your product. this code should work.. let me know

Comment: Looking at the string of errors its showing the name of the item and the description but just looping through it and printing it millions of times...

Comment: can you give me your full .php file of this one or full page code you are using? It is hard to say what is the issue on the fly. because I have tested the code which I sent you.

Comment: Just added the whole page to my Question

Comment: Finally re-posted the answer by considering your total code. Tested and works fine.. Let me know the status..

Comment: That is brilliant, the only thing that isn;t showing anymore is the description, are you seeing that on yours?

Comment: Yes I see the description as well
Try this. may be this will help
**Remove**
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post->post_excerpt ); ?>
**Add**
<?php echo $product->post->post_excerpt; ?>

Comment: Its strange.. Make sure you have description on the product not the long description. this will get the short description. try adding both description to the product and see

Comment: You have been an absolute Gentleman. I cannot thank you enough.